# Is this normal for a foreach inside a foreach?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

This is my code below. It uses `array_chunk()` to split the results into groups of three so I only have 3 columns per each `.row`.

```
   <?php
    $blogusers = get_users( 'exclude=1,12'); //WordPress's get_users()
    $split = array_chunk($blogusers,3); 

    // Array of WP_User objects.
    foreach ( $split as $user ) { 

        echo '<div class="row">';


          foreach ($user as $details){ 

            // get user profile picture or default to a plain one
            if (get_field('show', 'user_'.$details->ID)){ 
              $img = get_field('profile_pic','user_'.$details->ID); 
            }

          echo
           //output each user
           '<div class="columns small-4">
              <div class="profile">
                <div class="profile-image-wrap">      
                  <img src="'.$img.'" class="team-image">
                  <a href="" class="profile-hover-link"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-bars fa-3x"></i></a>      
                </div>    
                <div class="profile-details-wrap">
                  <h4>'.$details->display_name.'</h4>
                  <h5>'.the_field('title', 'user_'.$details->ID).'</h5>
                  <div class="hr-wrap">
                    <hr class="team-hr">
                  </div>                                
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam aliquam massa quis mauris sollicitudin commodo.</p>
                  <a class="view" href="">view profile</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>';               
          }
        echo '</div>'; 
      }
```

The problem is with this line

`<h5>'.the_field('title', 'user_'.$details->ID).'</h5>`

It doesn't insert the output into that `<h5>` tag as seen below.

[image]

**I've tried using double and single quotes on that line but that doesn't fix it.**

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are using the [Advanced Custom Fields plugin](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/). If you look at the [docs for `the_field`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/), you'll see that it

> Displays the value of the specified field. This function is the same as `echo get_field($field_name);`

Which is exactly what you want. In your case, you want the function to return the field's value, not print it. So, change your line to

```
<h5>'.get_field('title', 'user_'.$details->ID).'</h5>
```

and you're good to go.

The problem in your case is that you're building a string before printing it out to the browser. During this building phase, you're calling `the_field`, which does its own `echo`ing. That's why the title appears before the whole div.